# How to make columns of datagridview responsive so not all columns don't change their width

Tags: c#

[image] I want to align datagridview columns to right but I dont want to change width of column of my datagridview which I set. I've got eight columns second column's property "resizable" is set to true the rest is "resizable = "false. When I expand datagridview or window the width of columns except second should not expand. How to do it. Property Fill doesn't work like I want. I expadns all columns and gives them their own width. But I want to leave width of my columns as they're already set except of the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps:

1. Set `AutoSizeColumnsMode` of the DataGridView control to *Fill*.
2. Set `AutoSizeMode` of the second column to *None*, leave other columns as *NotSet* (default value).

Now you should see that only the width of the second column is fixed, the width is controlled by *Width*, for other columns you can change *FillWeight* to control the ratio of width.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very helpful. But the solution what I was looking for, was the second column should be set "NotSet" and the rest "None". But it was very helpful